# A problem regarding the transformation of graphs.

Tags: linear-transformations, graphing-functions

[image]

I'm really not sure what to do from here onwards. The only thing that I've ascertained so far is that $f(m)=f(n)=0$, but given that I do not know the values of $m$ or $n$ it doesn't mean anything to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shift the graph k units along the positive x-axis.

Comment: @RamanujanXV $k$ is defined as $n-m$ and I'm not sure what either value is.

Comment: k is *less than* n-m.

Comment: @aayush k would be somewhere between m and n on the x axis.

Comment: To build intuition I recommend you graph  several functions $f(x)$ and compare them to the graph of the function $f(x-k)$. Use this intuition to solve this problem.